# AJAX request confusion in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to understand that why the jquery AJAX is not fetching data from the ajax page.
Can someone please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#lms_id').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
        //    alert("1");
        } else {
        //    alert("0");
        }
    });

    $('#lms_user_role_id').change(function(){
        if (($(this).val() == "7" || $(this).val() == "8")) {
            $('#t_lms_dealers').show();
        } else {
            $('#t_lms_dealers').hide();
        }
    });
});

      function loadAjax(message)
      {
      //alert(message);
      //$.get("<?php echo $App['wwwroot'].'er.php' ?>?activity="+message);
      $.get("http://www.abc.loc/er.php");


      }
      </script>
```

In loadAjax function, alert is alerting fine, but only the AJAX part is not working.

Comment: this page (http://www.abc.loc/lmsapi/LMS_L2/templates/admin/user/tpl.user_dealer.php) doesn't respond at all

Comment: this is part of my page, which is of several lines

Comment: this function is loading the alert message fine, but not only the AJAX part

Comment: What should happen in your opinion? Your just calling the url via a get request. Nothing more, nothing less...

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, that's it i want, using ajax

Comment: @MohanSinfh Does the request fail? Is there any error in the console? See also goldilocks answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know it is "not working"?

```
$.get("http://www.abc.loc/lmsapi/LMS_L2/templates/admin/user/tpl.user_dealer.php");
```

Even if it did, this statement would accomplish nothing.  You need to put a handler in there:

```
$.get(
    "http://www.abc.loc/lmsapi/LMS_L2/templates/admin/user/tpl.user_dealer.php",
    function (data) {
        alert("Retrieved :"+data);
    }
);
```

You should also use some kind of in browser developer tool (eg, **firebug**) that will allow you to trace the request in real time.  Finally, the plain jquery `get` lacks an error handler; you might want to instead use:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "http://www.abc.loc/lmsapi/LMS_L2/templates/admin/user/tpl.user_dealer.php",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, err, code) {
        alert("Error: "+err);
    }
});
```

And read the query documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong 2nd possibility is may be you are trying "cross domain ajax call", if yes then you have to set header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and "crossDomain: true" for $.ajax call.